# Failed prop type: The prop `authors` is marked as required in `Book`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, undefined, react-proptypes

I am creating an app in which the user can search for a book using an api call. I am getting this error whenever I search for a book. The reason is because the authors array is initially undefined. But this doesn't happen with the title or the thumbnail. Any way to fix this error?

Searchpage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BsArrowLeftShort } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { debounce } from 'debounce';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import { search } from '../api/BooksAPI';
import Book from '../components/Book';

const SearchPage = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const bookSearch = debounce(() => {
      if (query.length > 0) {
        search(query).then((res) => {
          if (res.length > 0) setData(res);
          else setData([]);
        });
      } else {
        setData([]); // make sure data is not undefined
      }
    }, 1000);
    bookSearch();
  }, [query]);

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar
        type="text"
        searchValue={query}
        placeholder="Search for a book"
        icon={<BsArrowLeftShort />}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
      {console.log(data)}
      {data.map((book) => {
        console.log(book.authors);
        return (
          <Book
            key={book.id}
            title={book.title}
            authors={book.authors}
            thumbnail={book.imageLinks.thumbnail}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

Book.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Book = ({ title, authors, thumbnail }) => (
  <div>
    <img src={thumbnail} alt={title} />
    <div>{title}</div>
    <div>{authors}</div>
  </div>
);

Book.propTypes = {
  thumbnail: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  authors: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
};

export default Book;
```

EDIT: here is a screenshot of the response from the promise. I added a console.log to the promise chain. The value of the authers array does not appear as undefined. Note this appears before the warning on the console.

[image]

Comment: Looks like `search(query)` returns an object that has the `authors` key undefined...

Comment: Or more specifically that `res` is an array of objects that don't have an `authors` property. What is the `res` response shape and value? (check either the network tab or just console log it in the Promise chain.

Comment: @Dominik yes this may be the case but I'm still confused

Comment: @DrewReese I have made an edit to my question, I have posted a screenshot of the console.log of the response above. As you can see, the authors array is populated. This appears before the warning in the console

Comment: All 20 of those objects would need a defined `authors` property. If any one of them doesn't have an `authors` property that will trigger the PropTypes warning/error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing to Book its required property in all the cases

`authors={book.authors || []}`

or put `authors` as not required prop in `Book` otherwise